# Push Notification for particular device in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi In my application I want to send the notification to specific device.can anyone please tell me what i have to add this code.sending to multiple devices its working but i want to send the specific devices.

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.PushService;

import android.app.Application;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Add your initialization code here
        //Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");
        //Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        Parse.initialize(this, "C2yxkDNMYElOezmEogThD9juS41XbF9ReGq2Avfx", "eL5aveox8KmGfUF613d9PjLhwvCM8aV7MTvV5wH8");

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, abc.class);



    }
```

Thank you,

Comment: Don't put your actual Parse data in a public question - replace them with placeholders

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for how to target pushes: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/Android

Comment: Hi Iam Not Getting this tutorial